# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect with Pentaho HTTP Post in Unix box

Tags: soap, pentaho, kettle

Its bit strange, am getting this error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" with Pentaho Kettle's HTTP Post step in only Unix box. My development machine is Windows 7 and there I never faced this issue. But when I deploy my ETL job at Unix box and execute, will get this error.

I had figured-out the issue. Here, the SOAP request XML includes Unicode characters; if I replace this with normal alphabets, will get executed properly.

But my question is, why this issue is only in Unix (Red hat) box? Why not in Windows7 not even in SOAP UI?  Do I have to configure Unix to handle Unicode? or have to change my XML request for Unix?

My XML Request format is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bul="http://www.uidai.gov.in/bulkseed">
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <bul:bulkSeedRequest>
       <bul:bulkSeedDetails>
         <bul:userLoginId>WS_USER_ID</bul:userLoginId>
         <bul:uid>123456789</bul:uid>
         <bul:benificiaryId>ABC123</bul:benificiaryId>
         <bul:deptId>1</bul:deptId>
         <bul:schemeId>2</bul:schemeId>
         <bul:districtId>3</bul:districtId>
         <bul:talukaId>4</bul:talukaId>
         <bul:benificiaryName>ಕೃಷ್ಣಮಣಿ</bul:benificiaryName>
         <bul:benificiaryGender>F</bul:benificiaryGender>
         <bul:benificiaryDOB/>
         <bul:benificiaryAge>030</bul:benificiaryAge>
         <bul:benificiaryAddress>House Address</bul:benificiaryAddress>
        <bul:familyMemberId>2</bul:familyMemberId>
        <bul:action>ADD</bul:action>
      </bul:bulkSeedDetails>
    </bul:bulkSeedRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be caused by the default encoding in java.  On Windows it is NOT UTF-8.  On unix it is UTF-8. And I guess those chars don't work in UTF-8?

you can configure it like so:

[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

I suspect if you set PDI to UTF-8 on windows (as above) then you'll be able to reproduce in Windows too.